# Make strapi sort entries by id/createdAt by default

Tags: strapi

I'm using Strapi v4.1.7

On my local machine when I run strapi (sqlite) on dev mode and I make a api request (rest/graphql) I get the results sorted by id/createdAt from oldest ---> newest.

But when I deployed to heroku (production mode PostgreSQL) and I make the request I get the results sorted by updatedAt from oldest ---> newest.

My question is: How can I make my production version behave the same as my developement version?

in other words How can I make strapi sort entries by id/createdAt by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to work for me in Strapi v4:

```
sort: "createdAt:DESC"
```

...

```
query GetVideos($page: Int!, $pageSize: Int!) {
    videos(
      pagination: { page: $page, pageSize: $pageSize }
      sort: "createdAt:DESC"
    ) {
      __typename
      data {
        __typename
        id
        attributes {
          __typename
          createdAt
          publishedAt              
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```